# Solve $(2xy-3x^2)dx+(x^2-2y)dy=0$

Tags: calculus

Same thing that the title suggests, I want to solve $(2xy-3x^2)dx+(x^2-2y)dy=0$. This equation is not separable, it is not something where I can find the integrating factor for. And I can not integrate straight away because it doesn't work with 2 variables. So...that rules out most of the options I have for solving it. I tried my best to rearrange this equation and I have $2xy-3x^2+(x^2-2y)\frac{dy}{dx}=0$. What should be the next step here? I want to be able to integrate and express this in terms of y. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

The proposed DE is exact. Indeed, one has
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(2xy - 3x^{2}) = 2x = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^{2} - 2y)
\end{align*}